# Uninstalling PWA for development testing (windows)

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I installed my PWA on windows through developer's console, and now can't uninstall it to test installing it. I've tried removing service worker from chrome, but it will just get reregistered after I open the PWA through windows (if server is on). When I right click on it and choose uninstall it takes me to windows app and features there's no entry for it, meanwhile the actual shortcut for it surely just leads to chrome with app ID in URL. Trying to install the PWA after everything I've tried will not give me the prompt again to add it to homescreen.

url: makpal.now.sh
screen:
[image]

Comment: To uninstall a PWA on Chrome OS, expand the launcher (to get the large icons), then right click on the app's icon and choose "Remove from Chrome...". If you don't see the app's icon, search for its name in the launcher.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The PWA apps reside in apps menu `chrome://apps/` of chrome, and quite possibly exclusively under a different tab (a grayish second bar at the bottom of window), which is where you'd get the option to delete them that works.

Comment: To clarify, this is found at `chrome://apps/`

Comment: Thanks, that worked, although I guess it's an MS bug because there is an option to delete it that currently redirects to Windows Control Panel desktop Apps uninstall menu which doesn't contain PWA applications

Answer (score 8):

EASY STEPS to Remove (uninstall) PWA App on Desktop:

1) Open Chrome Browser

2) Click > Apps button

3) Right click > App you want to remove

4) Select > Remove from Chrome... > Remove.

5) App gone. :)

On Mobile: drag to trashcan.

Answer (score 7):

If you installed PWA using chrome then paste below in chrome URL bar and hit enter:

```
chrome://apps
```

`Right click` on desired app and click `remove from chrome`

Answer (score 4):

Found the list of PWAs here.

```
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Chrome-Apps
```

You can delete them from there.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed to Windows OS using developer console, I assume you have done it using the Chrome menu -> "Install to desktop" (if it comes as "add to desktop, it means your site is not meeting minimum [PWA cirteria](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/checklist)).

If you have installed in any other way, please be specific on what option you have used. It also contradicts at the end of your question, where you were complaining on "Install prompt" is not coming again for "add to home screen". From all I know, install prompt is not supported in Chrome for Windows yet(I know it works in Chrome for Android).

On your other question on service worker getting re-registered every time you visit, that's how they are supposed to work. They will get registered even if you visit a PWA site(adding to home screen is not needed, it will still register service worker and you get all caching benefits)

You can test all these PWA behaviors for this PWA compliant site -> https://pwa.rocks/

If you need more clarity, please rephrase your question to what exactly is happening and what use case is failing, along with supporting code. A link your your site will be best to debug for the community, if that's publicly available.

Comment: yes, i totally did it through add to homescreen through dev console under app>manifest tab (there's no option in chrome).

Comment: For some reason, that functionality under manifest tab is not adding to the home screen even for some of the PWA sites that I've tested(https://www.pwabuilder.com/). That's not the option your end users will use though. Check on Chrome menu(refer to the screenshot in the answer) , you will have "Add to home screen" /"Install to home screen" depending on browser version and your sites PWA eligibility.

Comment: There were multiple questions in your original question. If the above comment/answer still doesn't solve your question, breakdown your question and be explicit on what exactly is not working with screenshot. Remember we don't see what you see. Not providing code/URL to test and even the image is a lot of guess work.

Comment: added url and screen. I forgot to point out absence of option to add to homescreen outside dev console, but I don't actually know where it would appear.

Comment: @janat08 You didn't forgot just that. You forgot to give all key info..code/URL/dev tools screenshot. Home screen option is not coming for a reason and from what I've validated, your site is not installed as a PWA in first place as its not meeting all PWA criteria. But if you want to ask a half baked question and settle with your own wrong answer, I'm leaving it here. Good luck!

Comment: i posted url along with screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The Most useful answer I found: (for chrome)

1. Open Chrome and go to apps
2. Right click the PWA you want to remove
3. Click on "Remove from Chrome..."

I faced the same issue when I was built my first PWA and then when I Open anything else with live server it directed me to my PWA site.

Answer (score 0):

You can also go to you windows control panel \ programs then uninstall from there. ( Referring to the PWA that you installed, not uninstalling the browser )